# EditText onTextChanged

Tags: java, android

Having a brain freeze on how best to approach this, I have a ton of EditText boxes,
I want to implement an ontextchanged so that when they input 1000000 (not using decimals)
I want the EditText to diplay $1,000,000 as they type. 
I am using this method for my outputs and works fine.

```
private String FormatValue(double value)
{
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();

    return "$ "+ nf.format(value);
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Ok, so what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try implementing a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). Look at [PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher](http://www.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/telephony/java/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.java&exact_package=android&q=PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher&type=cs) for an example.

Comment: I have a ton of EditText boxes, I want to implement an ontextchanged so that when they input 1000000 (not using decimals) I want the EditText to diplay $1,000,000 as they type. Wondering if theremight be anyexamples closer to what I need. Seems wierd that I can't find any similar to what I need

Comment: I think this is the same question as you asked above. Please take a close look at the PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher code. This does exactly what you want, but for phone numbers instead of dollar values. Take that implementation and tweak it for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks guys I found a great example of what I was looking for... http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/ConvertinputvaluetoCurrencyinTextWatcher.htm Having a problem implenting it... I will post new question for guidance